# CSS: Give a div a height that is a multiple of a number?

Tags: css, html, tile

A div has a tilable background. The height of this div will depend on its content. I need the div to stretch by a multiple of the background image's size.

For instance, the background is a 64x64 image.
So, if the div's height is to increase, I want to do so by steps of 64px.

Is this possible with CSS? I've not found leads using google. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can't do this in css - in general, css doesn't let you set styles conditional upon the content of a dynamically sized element.

Comment: In simple css it can't be achieve. Try jQuery for that.

Comment: @newuser - You don't need jQuery to do this and plain javascript will do the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my knowledge this cannot be done in CSS, but you could probably solve it with some javascript. If you have access to jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $div = $('#the_div_id');
    var remainder = $div.height() % 64;
    var newHeight = $div.height() + (64-remainder);
    $div.css('height', newHeight);
});
```

Comment: Yep, I think I'll go down that way, after the document gets ready. thanks =)

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, `$(function() { ... });` is shorthand for "do this when the DOM is ready", in case you are new to jQuery. And as @Rob said, it can be done in native Javascript as well, I just personally prefer jQuery.

Comment: I used your answer in a similar way that just tip toes around heights a little differently:  
    $pageContent = $('#pageContent');
    var remainder = $div.height() % 64;
    remainder = 64 -remainder;
    $div.css('padding-bottom', remainder);  if you're trying to use heights other places in your css that you don't want to modify, this will grow the div to a proper height

Answer (score 7):

One solution (depending on your specific case) could be to use the new `background-size` CSS property. I've left the declarations separate for clarity:

```
div.yourDiv {
    background-image: url('yourImage.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Then, whatever the size of you `div`, your image will tile perfectly without being cut off. Older browsers will just get the tiled image, which may or may not be an issue.

Comment: very interesting, am trying this out now!

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of the div? It sounds like rather than setting the size of the div to the correct value, you need to pay attention to the content - [this post](http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm) details some pretty simple techniques to implement vertical rhythm, which should work (ie. by using a line height of 64px)

Comment: It's actually about a kitsch ui: The div represents a ladder, and its height is proportional to the div's height from the top of the screen - makes tiling necessary as to connect to the terminator elements.